# Is there a DLL for supporting the Google Drive API in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I need to store a bulk amount of videos in to Google Drive, and I should download them later to play the videos. I found the Google Drive API DLL in Objective but I didn't find any DLLs in Monotouch. Is there any DLL for supporting the Google Drive API in Xamarin iOS?

Answer (score -1):

I see a Xamarin project in GitHub for this - https://github.com/xamarin/google-apis